# click icon and open target directly

Tags: mediawiki

I have a table in my wiki as below.  Right now when I click on the red pdf icon it takes me to the *file description page* for the target file, `myfile.pdf`.

Instead, I want it to immediately open the `myfile.pdf`, not require 2 clicks to get it open.

[image]

Below is what that table cell entry looks like (1st row, 2nd col in the table).  How do I modify it to do what i want?

```
[[Image:Pdf_icon.png|20px|link=File:myfile.pdf]]
```

Comment: Hi @KJ, yes I did and it made no difference.  It still goes to the pdf's description page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the following methods:

```
[[Image:Pdf_icon.png|20px|link=Special:FilePath/myfile.pdf]]
```

or

```
[[Image:Pdf_icon.png|20px|link={{filepath:myfile.pdf}}]]
```

The slight difference is that the first method links to an internal special page that automatically redirects to the file, and the second method generates a direct link to the file.